# What does the split("[\t ]") from line

Tags: java, file, split, line

I'm parsing a line from a file.

```
String tokens[] = line.split("[\t ]+");
```

I understand what it should do but I'm not getting the objective of the \t.

Can anyone explain me?

Comment: `\t` is the tab character. `[\t ]+` is a regular expression saying any sequence of 1 or more tabs/spaces.

Comment: Splits the line on one or more tabs/spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `[...]` [*Character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - matches one character in between the brackets.

  - `\t` The tab character
  - A space
- `+` [*Quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) - match the previous token 1 or more times.

Examples:

```
"foo   bar qux"   => ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
"foo\t  bar\tqux" => ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
```

You might want to use the `\s` whitespace meta character, which is equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f ]`.

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is a tab space character...

it is used to add tab spaces in strings but do make sure to use `\\` in `Split` function to escape the first `\`

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is a tabulator character. So in this case you have a `String line`, that may contain `\t` characters and you split this String by tabulator into an array.

Answer (score 1):

\t is a tab space escape character,but i think in your case you should use:

```
str.split("\\s+");
```

if you want to split between even a single white space

Answer (score -2):

Try `\\t` instead of `\t`. Split function needs to see the escape character.